# Python RegEx: Tokenizing string of key/value pairs using finditer

Tags: python-3.x

I have a sample string, and I want to extract all key/value pair from it.
Here is my code snippet:

```
import re

sample_string = r"""
$key1 = 'val1';
$key2 = 'val2';
$key3 = 'val3';
$key4 = 'val4';

$key5 = (
  {
    key1   => 'val1',
    key2   => 'val2',
  },
);

"""

reg_exp = re.compile(r"\$(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*?);")
for match in reg_exp.finditer(sample_string, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
    ss = match.groups()
    print(ss)
```

My code only recognizes some of the key/values pairs.

```
('key3', "'val3'")
('key4', "'val4'")
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Based on python documentation, `DOTALL` will cause `.` to match even newlines, which is not good because it can cause issue on your matching with lines and also your keys and values doesn't contain line break, so I removed it.

Another point here is, flags are for the compile function, and you cannot use flags with compiled regex as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer).

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(
    r"""\$(.+)\s*=\s*(.*|\(\s*\{\s*(\s*(.+)\s*=>\s*(.+),?\s*)+\s*\},?\s*\));""",
    re.M,
)

text = """
$key1 = 'val1';
$key2 = 'val2';
$key3 = 'val3';
$key4 = 'val4';

$key5 = (
  {
    key1   => 'val1',
    key2   => 'val2',
  },
);
"""

for match in regex.finditer(text):
    print(match)
    ss = match.groups()
    print(ss)
```

In the final version, I've also updated the regex for the last `key5` but you need to parse its value further to key its keys.

Comment: Thanks! in that case, if I move the flags into compile, my own solution is working! that was the subtle issue with my solution then ;) thanks for bringing it to my attention.